# Memory Management in the android environment

Tags: android, android-memory

I've been looking into memory management lately, and I create a `Service` like this:

```
public class MemoryManagerService extends Service {

    private boolean isRunning = true;
    private Thread memoryThread;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Log.v("MemoryThread: ", "Created");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        memoryThread = new Thread(new MemoryManagerThread());
        memoryThread.start();
        Log.v("MemoryThread: ", "Started");
        isRunning = true;
        return START_STICKY;
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        //memoryThread.stop();
        Log.v("MemoryThread: ", "Stopped");
        isRunning = false;
    }

    private class MemoryManagerThread implements Runnable
    {
        public MemoryManagerThread() {

        }

        @Override
        public void run() {

            while(isRunning) {
                try 
                {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                    Log.v("Allocated bytes", Long.toString(Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() - Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()));
                }
                catch(Exception e) {}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which will only output the allocated memory each 5 seconds. This service is started from the my main `activity`. Of course the application will allocate memory, but what am worried about is the increasing memory.

I've seen in `LogCat` that every 5 seconds the allocated bytes increases by `80 bytes`, which means `16 bytes/sec`. Not very big numbers here, but it could be if the application is running "forever", or until the `GC` is starting. When the application starts it uses about `14 mb` of memory. I should also mentioned that I've barely seen the `GC_CONCURRENCE`, which means that the `GC` is running due to low memory. Should I be worried regarding the memory in my app?

Comment: Is this an actual app? Looks a little useless to me.

Comment: I've just created a service to start from my actual app, to monitor the memory of the application and just to see how the memory is behaving.

Comment: do you have memory problems? And why not use the SDK's memory profiling tools?

Comment: I've fixed my memory problems, and yes I've used the MAT tool to analyze. My question was a bit theoretical regarding the increasing heap, is it a normal thing maybe unnormal..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would bet that if you only slept your thread for 3000 that you would gain 80 bytes every three seconds.  Lots of little things allocate memory in your app, then it is available to be cleaned up at some (usually inopportune) point.

Comment: so nothing to worry about as long as I dont see the `GC 4% 24+2ms` stuff?

Comment: Yes.  Nothing to worry about.